# For IIS, what is the best way to update static files while maintaining availability on a live website?

Tags: iis

I've investigated this and found lots of related information, but nothing that answers my question.

A little background. A small set of files are shared by IIS 10 statically. These files need to be updated usually weekly, but not more than once an hour (unless someone manually runs an update utility for testing). The files are expected to be a couple K bytes in size, no larger then 10 kilobytes. The update process can be run on the IIS server and will be written in PowerShell or C#.

My plan for updating files that are actively being served as static files by IIS is:

- Copy the files to a temporary local location (on the same volume)
- Attempt to move the files to the IIS static site location

  - The move may fail if the file is in use (by IIS). Implement a simple retry strategy for this.

It doesn't cause a problem if there is a delay in publishing these files. What I really want to avoid is IIS trying to access one of the files at just the wrong time, a race condition while my file replacement is in process. I have no control over the HTTP client which might be a program that's not tolerant of the type of error IIS could be expected to return, like an HTTP status 404, "Not Found".

I have a couple random ideas:

- HTTP GET the file from IIS before I replace it with the intention of getting the file into IIS's cache in hopes that will improve the situation.
- Just ignore this potential issue an hope for the best

I can't be the only developer who's faced this. What's a good way to address this issue? (Or is it somehow not an issue at all and I'm just over thinking it?)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The common practice is 1) Use load balancing so you have more than one web servers. 2) Remove a server out of the cluster, and update files there. 3) Put the server back. 4) Do this for the rest.

Comment: @LexLi, thanks. That's probably the "right" way. I think we can use a Load Balancer, but I won't have access to any LB API. But if I can stop the static site (or IIS service) safely, completing pending requests, then that might allow the LB to recover the error and retry on a different server. I'll ask the network infrastructure team for help, but it will either be a hard no or 6 months out. I should be able to find how they monitor the health of the backend servers and use that to get the LB to remove a server.

Comment: Another way, less common, is to have all files in a single directory hierarchy, and to deploy, you create a completely new hierarchy, then move the root. This works well on linux, might work less well with windows.

Comment: @arnt, in a way that validates my plan, except I'm doing the move file by file (for less than 10 files). If done right, I think this can mostly work on Windows, but without atomic file operations, there's a slight chance of a race condition, so not 100%. These are small files which helps minimize (or eliminate) the failure window. Thanks for your comment.